# How to create barplots with two continuous on with consent value in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is part of my data

```
df<-read.table (text=" Id   KI  OI
id1 79  69
id2 43  69
id3 68  69
id4 76  69
id5 74  69
id6 66  69
id7 49  69
id8 24  69
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get barplots for each id using a single graph. So x-axis is ids and y-axis values.
For example in the plot, I want to see Id1 with bars of 79 and 69 together and so on with a clear legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot your data into long format, then plotting is very straightforward. I have added a theme and fill scale for illustration too.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Id, value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "deepskyblue4") +
  scale_fill_brewer() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

An example of alternate styling:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Id, value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black", width = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("deepskyblue4", "orange")) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

Comment: @user330 there are a huge number of options for you to style the plot however you see fit. You asked how to plot your data with the ids on the x axis and the values from the two columns plotted side by side. I have shown how to do that in ggplot. The final look of the plot is up to you, and I can't presume to know your tastes. If you like I will add a variation in the style as an example? It is usual when plotting a bar plot to leave a gap between groups of bars, in contrast to a histogram where all the bars touch. The gap is very much intentional here.

Comment: @user330 I've added an alternative styling. See what you think. I'm pretty sure that no-one else is going to add an answer just to offer styling suggestions for your plot - unless you want to specify a particular style and are stuck with how to do that? Remember, SO is for specific coding problems - not for design advice. Good luck finding what you need, either way.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is that when I use it in my real data ids are not in order. For example, id7, id4,id3,... Could also help me to get an increment of  4 in Y-axis

Comment: @user330 ggplot will sort the x axis alphabetically by default. If you want to plot the ids in the order they appear in your data frame, try `df$Id <- factor(df$Id, unique(df$Id))` and re-running your plot